# How to do real time data ingestion from Transactional tables to a Flat table

Tags: oracle, data-warehouse, real-time-data

We have transaction tables in Oracle and for reporting purposes we need this data transfered in real time to another flat Oracle table in another database. The performance of the report is great with table placed in this flat table. 
Currently we are using golden gate for replication to the other database and using materialized view for this but due to some problems we need to switch to some other way of populating/maintaining this flat table. What options do we have?
It is a pretty basic requirement but the solutions I can see are for batch processing. Also if there are any other solutions you feel would better serve this purpose. Changing the target database to something other is also an option as there might be more such reports coming ahead.

Comment: Streaming with Kafka is popular these days. [Find out more](https://rmoff.net/2018/12/12/streaming-data-from-oracle-into-kafka-december-2018/)